# SQL Group BY SUM one column and select of first row of grouped items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a part table where I have 5 fields.  I want to sum the QTY of the mfgpn while showing the first returned row for the other 3 fields (Manfucturer, DateCode, Description).  I initially thought of using the MIN function as follows, but that doesn't really help me insofar as that the data is not a int data type.  How would I go about doing this?  Right now I'm stuck at the following query below:

```
SELECT SUM([QTY]) AS QTY
  ,[MFGPN]
  ,MIN([MANUFACTURER]) AS MANUFACTURER
  ,MIN([DATECODE]) AS DateCode
  ,MIN([DESCRIPTION]) AS DESCRIPTION
  INTO part
GROUP BY MFGPN, MANUFACTURER, DATECODE, description
ORDER BY mfgpn ASC
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and the output you'd like to see from that data. It makes it much easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It sounds like you really want *two* queries. Nothing wrong with that... simple = good

Comment: if u really want it in "one query" you can do sub queries in the select clause itself SELECT (select top 1 somthing from something where...) , ...

Comment: Nothing wrong with a nested query provided that it gives the right results.

Comment: Ho would you define a first row.You need to provide a proper way which oen you consider first row like the row with latest datecode is one which is first row etc..

Answer (score 4):

Would `CROSS APPLY` work for you?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(a.[QTY]) AS QTY
    ,a.[MFGPN]
    ,c.[MANUFACTURER]
    ,c.[DATECODE]
    ,c.[DESCRIPTION]
FROM part a
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM part b WHERE a.[MFGPN] = b.[MFGPN]) c
GROUP BY 
    a.[MFGPN]
    ,c.[MANUFACTURER]
    ,c.[DATECODE]
    ,c.[DESCRIPTION]
```

---

Tested with the following:

```
DECLARE @T1 AS TABLE (
    [QTY] int
    ,[MFGPN] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[MANUFACTURER] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[DATECODE] DATE
    ,[DESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT @T1 VALUES
(2, 'MFGPN-1', 'MANUFACTURER-A', '20120101', 'A-1'),
(4, 'MFGPN-1', 'MANUFACTURER-B', '20120102', 'B-1'),
(3, 'MFGPN-1', 'MANUFACTURER-C', '20120103', 'C-1'),
(1, 'MFGPN-2', 'MANUFACTURER-A', '20120101', 'A-2'),
(5, 'MFGPN-2', 'MANUFACTURER-B', '20120101', 'B-2')

SELECT 
    SUM(a.[QTY]) AS QTY
    ,a.[MFGPN]
    ,c.[MANUFACTURER]
    ,c.[DATECODE]
    ,c.[DESCRIPTION]
FROM @T1 a
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @T1 b WHERE a.[MFGPN] = b.[MFGPN]) c
GROUP BY 
    a.[MFGPN]
    ,c.[MANUFACTURER]
    ,c.[DATECODE]
    ,c.[DESCRIPTION]
```

Produces

```
QTY MFGPN   MANUFACTURER    DATECODE    DESCRIPTION
9   MFGPN-1 MANUFACTURER-A  2012-01-01  A-1
6   MFGPN-2 MANUFACTURER-A  2012-01-01  A-2
```

Comment: Looks like that does exactly what I'm trying to do in a single query.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have thought of approaching the problem like that. Your use of `TOP 1` without an explicit `ORDER BY` might boost the performance of your query a little bit, but it might also make the results indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily managed with a [windowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) `SUM()`:

```
WITH summed_and_ranked AS (
  SELECT
    MFGPN,
    MANUFACTURER,
    DATECODE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    QTY = SUM(QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY MFGPN),
    RNK = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY MFGPN
      ORDER BY DATECODE  -- or which column should define the order?
    )
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  MFGPN,
  MANUFACTURER,
  DATECODE,
  DESCRIPTION,
  QTY,
INTO parts
FROM summed_and_ranked
WHERE RNK = 1
;
```

For every row, the total group quantity and the ranking within the group is calculated. When actually getting rows for inserting into the new table (the main SELECT), only rows with `RNK` values of 1 are pulled. Thus you get a result set containing group totals as well as details of certain rows.